# Clojure recursive macro expansion in the repl

Tags: recursion, clojure, macros, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

This is a simplified example and the point of the question is to understand how to debug recursive macros and understanding how macroexpand works in the REPL.

This is the example code I have pasted to a `lein repl`:

```
(defn f1 [& params] (map inc params))

(defmacro a [x]
  (if (= (count x) 0)
    ()
    (let [first-x (first x)]
      (if (= (count x) 1)
        `(f1 ~first-x)
        (let [rest-x (rest x)]
          `((f1 ~first-x) (a ~rest-x)))))))
```

This is what I get:

```
user=> (f1 3)
(4)
user=> (f1 2 3 4)
(3 4 5)
user=> (macroexpand '(a ()))
()
user=> (macroexpand '(a (12)))
(user/f1 12)
user=> (macroexpand '(a (8 14)))
((user/f1 8) (user/a (14)))
user=> (macroexpand-all '(a (8 14)))

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: macroexpand-all in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init1519958991634351316.clj:1:1) 
user=>
```

The f1 function simply increments values, this is a simplified example for demonstration.

The `macroexpand '(a ()))` and `(macroexpand '(a (12)))` lines do what I wanted.

Here comes the question part:

How can I fix this, so `(macroexpand '(a (8 14)))` will evaluate to

```
((user/f1 8) (user/f1 14))
```

in the `repl` and not stop expanding here:

```
((user/f1 8) (user/a (14)))
```

I tried also macroexpand-all, but it throws, see above.

Comment: `macroexpand-all` is in clojure.walk, you need to access it via that namespace.

Comment: that solved it. thanks a lot. why don"t you move your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `clojure.walk/macroexpand-all` which can be found in the `clojure.walk` namespace, which is part of clojure.core.

The last part from the question now works:

```
user=> (clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(a (8 14)))
((user/f1 8) (user/f1 14))
```